# Creating CSV and add data in ArcGIS Pro with Python

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have a script in ArcGIS that extracts some data and coordinates from a CGXML file and I would like this script to create a CSV table for me, to add columns, to choose what data to enter in those columns in the file and once again I want to only accept CGXML files in which there is no information related to coordinates, ie X and Y. Here you have a model that I worked on but so far it creates my CSV file but does not add the data from the files without coordinates. Do you have any suggestions?

````
import arcpy
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import itertools
import csv

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

input_cgxml = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
Land_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Building_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
output_csv = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

# create an empty list to store the points
all_points_data = []

# loop through the input CGXML files
for cgxml in input_cgxml:
    # parse the CGXML file
    tree = ET.parse(arcpy.Describe(cgxml).catalogPath)
    root = tree.getroot()

    # Extract file name from the <FileDescription> tag
    file_el = root.find("FileDescription")
    if file_el is not None:
        filename_el = file_el.find("FILENAME")
        if filename_el is not None:
            file_name = filename_el.text
        else:
            file_name = ""
    else:
        file_name = ""
        
    # Extract Sector
    file_el = root.find("Land")
    if file_el is not None:
        cadsector_el = file_el.find("CADSECTOR")
        if cadsector_el is not None:
            cad_sector = cadsector_el.text
        else:
            cad_sector = ""
    else:
        cad_sector = ""
    #Extract Persons
    persons = root.findall("Person")
    fullnames = []
    person_ids = []
    for person in persons:
        firstname_el = person.find("FIRSTNAME")
        if firstname_el is not None:
            firstname = firstname_el.text
        else:
            firstname = ""
        lastname_el = person.find("LASTNAME")
        if lastname_el is not None:
            lastname = lastname_el.text
        else:
            lastname = ""
        fullname = ""
        if firstname:
            fullname += firstname
        if lastname:
            if fullname:
                fullname += " "
            fullname += lastname
        fullnames.append(fullname)
        personid_el = person.find("PERSONID")
        if personid_el is not None:
            personid = personid_el.text
            person_ids.append(personid)
    # Extract suprafata acte land and Building
    file_el = root.find("Land")
    if file_el is not None:
        act_sup_land = file_el.find("PARCELLEGALAREA")
        if act_sup_land is not None:
            act_sup_land = act_sup_land.text
        else:
            act_sup_land = ""
    else:
        act_sup_land = ""
    if file_el is not None:
        act_sup_building = file_el.find("BUILDINGLEGALAREA")
        if act_sup_building is not None:
            act_sup_building = act_sup_building.text
        else:
            act_sup_building = ""
    else:
        act_sup_building = ""
    # Extract CF Vechi
    if file_el is not None:
        cf_vechi = file_el.find("PAPERLBNO")
        if cf_vechi is not None:
            cf_vechi = cf_vechi.text
        else:
            cf_vechi = ""
    else:
        cf_vechi = ""
    #Extract Cad Vechi
    if file_el is not None:
        cad_vechi = file_el.find("PAPERCADNO")
        if cad_vechi is not None:
            cad_vechi = cad_vechi.text
        else:
            cad_vechi = ""
    else:
        cad_vechi = ""
    # Extract E2IDENTIFIER values for land and building parent tags
    file_el = root.find("Land")
    if file_el is not None:
        e2identifier_land = file_el.find("E2IDENTIFIER")
        if e2identifier_land is not None:
            e2identifier_land = e2identifier_land.text
        else:
            e2identifier_land = ""
    else:
        e2identifier_land = ""
    file_el = root.find("Building")
    if file_el is not None:
        e2identifier_building = file_el.find("E2IDENTIFIER")
        if e2identifier_building is not None:
            e2identifier_building = e2identifier_building.text
        else:
            e2identifier_building = ""
    else:
        e2identifier_building = ""
        
    # loop through the Points elements in the CGXML file
    points_el = root.findall("Points")
    points_data = []
    for point_el in points_el:
        x = point_el.find("X").text
        y = point_el.find("Y").text
        x_value = x.text if x is not None else "0 (default value)"
        y_value = y.text if y is not None else "0 (default value)"
        land_id = point_el.find("IMMOVABLEID")
        if land_id is not None:
            land_id = "Land-" + land_id.text
        else:
            land_id = ""
        building_id = point_el.find("BUILDINGID")
        if building_id is not None:
            building_id = "Building-" + building_id.text
        else:
            building_id = ""
        cat = ""
        if land_id:
            cat = "Land"
            e2_identifier = e2identifier_land
            act_sup = act_sup_land
            cf_vechi = cf_vechi
        elif building_id:
            cat = "Building"
            e2_identifier = e2identifier_building
            act_sup = act_sup_building
        else:
            e2_identifier = ""
            act_sup = ""
            cf_vechi = ""
        if x and y:
            points_data.append((x_value, y_value, cat, land_id, building_id, file_name, cad_sector, e2_identifier, ", ".join(fullnames),personid, act_sup, cf_vechi))
    all_points_data.append(points_data)

# flatten the list of points data
points_data = [point for sublist in all_points_data for point in sublist]

# create the output CSV file
import csv

fieldnames = ["X", "Y", "Category", "Land ID", "Building ID", "File Name", "CAD Sector", "E2 Identifier", "Full Names", "Person ID", "Actual Surface", "CF Vechi"]

with open("output_csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for point in points_data:
        if not point[0] or not point[1]: # X or Y is empty
            row = {"X": "", "Y": "", "Category": point[2], "Land ID": point[3], "Building ID": point[4], "File Name": point[5], "CAD Sector": point[6], "E2 Identifier": point[7], "Full Names": point[8], "Person ID": point[9], "Actual Surface": point[10], "CF Vechi": point[11]}
            writer.writerow(row)```
````

Comment: Where can I download a sample CGXML file? I have never heard of this file format before and can't find any file to download.

Comment: This type of file is used in my contry to store parcel and buildings and details about that. It's a xml file but much more structured. You can't download because it's something done personally by us, not by an institution or it's not something public. If you want, I can send you the script.

Comment: Could you post a very simple (anonymized) example with 1 or 2 records in the question? The records could be fantasy geometries. That would help.

Comment: Also, could you clarify a bit more what you need? I understand that your script should only read files (or records?) without X/Y information? Is that the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, the file code is too long, so I put a link to Drive that contains two files, one with coordinates and one without coordinates. I hope it's ok like that. If needed, I can also provide the rest of the code from the posted script in which I create shapefiles for Lands and Buildings.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dpYjv4sfZnbh6tN_PahyDsRUAUsBehzA?usp=share_link

Comment: Ok, my script extracts information from CGXML tags and stores them, the information being later used to create shapefiles that contain the Lands and Buildings that are stored in CGXML. But I noticed that if there is CGXML without coordinates, they are skipped, but I also want the information from those files. Initially, I wanted the script to add my row with the information from those files without coordinates without creating a polygon, so I thought that those files should be inserted into the csv. If it is possible to create a row for those without polyon, it would be even better.

Comment: Sorry I got distracted. I'll try to have a look in the next few days. But you can't have records without a geometry in a shapefile. So the approach to save them separate in a CSV file is the way to go. What you could do is to separate geometries (shapefile with id, x, y) and a table (csv or similar with all other fields) and then simply join them in ArcGIS Pro. Your script looks fine on first view (ignoring duplicated code ;)). Do you get any specific error?

Comment: I do not receive any error, the code is successfully completed, only that the CSV is empty and contains no information, only the table heads are added. If I take out the line: `if not point[0] or not point[1]: # X or Y is empty`, the script only adds information to me from the file with x and y but there's also a problem there that it takes out every point in that file, and the dots have the same information, but I would prefer it to be a single row of a CGXML in csv, not a row for each point. I think the mistake is were I create csv and add data or in section I extract data from CGXML.